# Outlook 2007: Gmail and POP3

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, pop3

I am using Microsoft Outlook 2007 for a number of my email accounts.  I have account A set up to come into my main inbox.  However, when I want to setup my Gmail account to come into a separate folder, but it comes into my main inbox, thus mixing mail from Account A with the Gmail account.  How do I get Gmail to download messages into its own folder, without a message rule?  If there is no other way to do it other than a rule, say so...

When I go to account settings and try to give the Gmail account its own Data file and deliver all Gmail mail there, it keeps reverting back to my Account A data file...Why is this? How can I fix it?

*Thanks!*

OS is Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using the IMAP protocol instead of POP3 for your gmail account.  If you do it this way you'll get folders for each gmail folder (or filter) in your account created automatically.

[Google's IMAP instructions](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=75725)

[image: outlook connected to my gmail account via imap]

Comment: I tried IMAP at first, but had to be connected to the web in order to read messages.  I want to be able to view and read messages along with replying to them, all while offline, and POP3 lets me do that...Can I make IMAP do this too (download a copy of the message to the computer automatically?)?

Comment: Is your problem just outlook not being set to download message bodies for offline use automatically, or it refusing to let you do anything with imap folders when offline?  I've configured outlook to do the former and can probably dig up the settings if needed.  I've only had the latter happen once and have no idea what was different that day from my normal situation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Outlook 2010 so I'm not sure if this will work in 2007.  With 2010 Outlook creates a PST file for each account.  I believe the PDF you are going to use for an account is defined in the dialog where you put the server information and username/password.

I believe Outlook would mount the second PST because each time Outlook launches because that account would connect to it.

Hope this work for Outlook 2007.